# TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__' in Python enumerate

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Hi I have code like below

my tupleList is =`[(0, '1.example'), (1, '2.example'), (2, '3. example'), (3, '4. example'), 0]`

```
Index = [x for x, y in enumerate(tupleList[0]) if y[0] == control]
self.list["list_key"].append(tupleList[0][Index[0]][1])
```

and my control variable is 1 and type int, I trying reach to '2.example' in tuple,

getting error

`TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__' in Python`

changing my tuple is = `[('E', '1 examp'), ('H', '2 examp'), 'E']`

like this and my control variable is 'E' is wont problem, code is working but I changing tupleList = `[(0, '1.example'), (1, '2.example'), (2, '3. example'), (3, '4. example'), 0]` and control variable to 1, I getting error

How can I procces this tupleList

Answer (score 1):

This is because strings are iterable, but ints aren't.

You could explicitly check for an integer:

```
[x for x, y in enumerate(tupleList[0]) if not isinstance(y, int) and y[0] == control]
```

or perhaps more generically:

```
from typing import Iterable
[x for x, y in enumerate(tupleList[0]) if isinstance(y, Iterable) and y[0] == control]
```